# How to replicate session variables in php to java?

Tags: java, php, authentication, session, intellij-idea

I am creating an application that manages inventory. I need to create a hierarchy of who can access the application. I have few ideas on the design but I don't know how to implement it.

I want to create a login that applies through the whole application.
For example, if I am logged in the login details will stay through the whole app until I close it. This way I can do an authentication check on various classes.

This is easy using session variable, but how can I replicate it in java when, by design, global variables are not allowed in java?

Comment: Many frameworks handle this for you; for example Spring for web based applications. I'd recommend you don't reinvent the wheel and use an existing framework instead.

Comment: Thanks, i'll study spring framework now

Comment: Improve syntax.